# How to use each_with_index in Ruby and to convert to numbered list?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering how do I convert an array to a numbered list using the `each_with_index`.

```
def roll_call_dwarves(dwarves)# code an argument here
  roll_call_dwarves = dwarves
  dwarves.each_with_index {|x, y|}
  puts dwarves
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by a numbered list, exactly? Can you show the output you want to get? Thanks.

Comment: Doc
Dopey
Bashful
Grumpy

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question isn't asked well. We'd like to see more effort put into your own solution. In addition, without an expected result we're going to come up with our own which might not be close to what you envision. See "[ask]" and its linked pages. As is your question is very broad.

Comment: Does the array have to have numbers and strings in each element, or does it have to be output to the console? We need more definition.

Comment: @MalcomFetus _"Doc Dopey Bashful Grumpy"_ isn't a numbered list, that's just 4 names. Please show some effort and edit your question to include the desired result. (there's an "edit" button)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, but if you just want to render the list with numbers, you could try something like:

```
def roll_call_dwarves(dwarves)
  dwarves.map.with_index do |dwarf, i|
    "#{i + 1}. #{dwarf}"
  end.join("\n")
end

dwarves = %w{Doc Dopey Bashful Grumpy}
puts roll_call_dwarves(dwarves)
```

This gives you:

```
1. Doc
2. Dopey
3. Bashful
4. Grumpy
```

Comment: That is excatly how the outcome should be but i don't know why the lab says to use each_with_index?

Comment: Rather than answer an ill-defined question work to get the question defined well first. That benefits the site and the OP much better than  shots in the dark.

Comment: @MalcomFetus A lab, like homework, expects to teach things in an order because succeeding lessons will build upon them.

Comment: A lot of educational institutions force you to use certain functions or programming constructs. Often, the requirements aren't the ideal solution to the problem so you often are forced to do it in a less than optimal way. Also, Ruby has a zillion ways of doing things, so it's very awkward to prescribe a single solution be used. Having said that, `map` is the wrong function here and `each_with_index` is a better approach. `map` creates a list that is just thrown out, so it's being abused as a foreach construct.